# shc-core: NoSuchMethodError org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.addColumn

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I try to use shc-core to save spark dataframe into hbase via spark.
My versions:

- hbase: 1.1.2.2.6.4.0-91
- spark: 1.6
- scala: 2.10
- shc: 1.1.1-1.6-s_2.10
- hdp: 2.6.4.0-91

Configuration looks like that:

```
val schema_array = s"""{"type": "array", "items": ["string","null"]}""".stripMargin

def catalog: String = s"""{
               |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"tblename"},
               |"rowkey":"id",
               |"columns":{
               |"id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"id", "type":"string"},
               |"col1":{"cf":"data", "col":"col1", "avro":"schema_array"}
               |}
               |}""".stripMargin 

df
.write
.options(Map(
    "schema_array"-> schema_array,
    HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog,
    HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"
))
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
.save()
```

Sometimes it works fine as expected and creates table and saves all the data into hbase. But sometimes just fail with following error:

```
Lost task 35.0 in stage 9.0 (TID 301, host): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.addColumn([B[B[B)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$hbase$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$hbase$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:210)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$hbase$HBaseRelation$$convertToPut$1(HBaseRelation.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseRelation$$anonfun$insert$1.apply(HBaseRelation.scala:219)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1111)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:247)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was actually a class path issue - I've got two different versions of hbase client.